# CSS ul li image to align with text

Tags: css

I have a CSS like this

```
ul {
    list-style-image:url(images/bulletArrow.gif);
}

ul li {
    background: url(images/hr.gif) no-repeat left bottom;
    padding: 5px 0 7px 0;
}
```

But the bullet image doesn't align properly in IE (it's fine in Firefox).
I already have a background image for li, so I can't use the bullet image as a background.
Is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to provide a bit more information?  Which version of IE are you using (if it's giving you that much trouble, it's probably IE6)?  Are you trying to align the image vertically with the text?  What does the image look like?  Just a simple horizontal rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you both of you.
The problem is that I already use background for a line-separator. But I'll change it to border then I'll use background for the bullet image.

Answer (score 24):

There is a good explanation and solution of this here: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/master.htm

It says that using `list-style-image` results in inconsistent placement of the image with different browsers. Then it explains how to use background images for the bullets for a better result.

Answer (score 3):

use line-height :)

Answer (score 2):

I see you're removing left padding for list items.  For IE, you need to do the same with the left margin - either completely remove it (set to zero) or make it something smaller than the default.  Then your list items will align nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
ul li {
    background: url(images/bulletArrow.gif);
    padding: 5px 30px 5px 25px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 180px 8px;
}
```

[this link](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-adjust-the-position-of-list-style-image.html) should be helpful.